# Linked-in webp support

Tags: image, posts, webp

As of this article posted in 2021, it looks like webp is not supported for Linked-In posts:
https://beamtic.com/webp-on-linkedin

I have a website with webp compressed images and my images are not showing in the posts. Does Linked-In still not have support for webp? If so, is there any plan to add support in the near future?